# How can I remap a Key+modifier output?

Tags: keyboard

Basically, there was Karabiner that did the job, but with Sierra it doesn't work anymore and there's still no updates. What are other ways to change shortcut output? 
In Particular I need to change ">" + Option that gives "≥" to give "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a custom keyboard layout to do this with Ukelele

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Comment: Can you please in short explain how do I add demanded modifications?

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives for software that can do this.
My preference has been [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net).

Comment: Wow thats some powerful multi feature tool